# Quero fazer uma barra com o meu logotipo e com o meu submenu

Tags: html, css

Como já referi no  meu  titulo, eu queria fazer uma barra. Eu não explicar bem  o que eu quero, mas eu vou deixar o link de um restaurante que tem o que eu quero  fazer: https://www.restaurantlarive.nl/nl/

Está aqui o meu  código

**Css:**

```
.menu ul li{
    background-color:#4d79ff;             /* muda a cor da barra */
    float: left;                   /* ficar horizontal */
    width: 120px;                  /* tamanho da barra */
    height: 50px;                  /* altura da barra */
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;             /* ficar a esqueda*/
    line-height: 22px;             /* mover o submenu*/
    font-size: 24px;               /* tamanho da letra*/
    position: relative;
}

.menu ul li:hover{
    background-color:#33adff;       /* muda a cor do submenu quando  metes la o rato */
}

.menu ul{
    padding: 0px;                   /* move a barra para a direita */
}

.menu ul ul{
    display: none;                  /* para  o sub sub menu ficar invisivel*/
}

.menu ul li:hover > ul{             /* para quando por o rato no menu ementa, aparecer o sub menu*/
    display:block;
}

.menu ul ul ul{                     /* SOBRE AS CARNES E PEIXES*/
    margin-left:120px;              /* mover para a direita*/
    top: 0px;                       /* ir para baixo*/
    position: absolute;
}

.menu ul ul li:hover{               /* SUBMENU DA EMENTA*/
    background-color:#80bfff;       /* cor do  submenu*/
}

.menu ul ul ul li:hover{            /* SUBSUBMENU DA EMENTA*/
    background-color:#80bfff;       /* cor*/
}

.menu a{                            /* OS MENUS*/
    color:black;                    /* cor do texto*/
    text-decoration: none;          /* sem decoração*/
}
```

**Html:**

```
<img src="33.png" href="quinta.html" width="150" height="150">
<body>
        <nav class="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Restaurante.html">Restaurante</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ementa</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Entrada.html">Entrada</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Prato Principal.html">Prato Principal</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="Carnes.html">Carnes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Peixes.html">Peixes</a></li>
                                <li><a href="Vegetariano.html">Vegetariano</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="Sobremesas.html">Sobremesas</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Reserva.html">Reserva</a></li>
                <li><a href="Contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
            </ul><br><br><br><br>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas pelo que li na sua pergunta e nos comentários acho que você quer o menu com o Blur e alinhado no centro da página correto.

Usei o CSS que o Thomas criou para fazer o Blur e adicionei esse CSS para alinhar o Menu e a Imagem no centro da página:

```
/* Alinhamento horizontal do Menu no Centro da Página*/
nav {
    width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Alinhamento horizontal da Imagem no Centro da Página*/
.hero {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Veja abaixo o Snippet completo funcionando. *Clique em Executar*.

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.menu ul li{
    background-color:#4d79ff;             /* muda a cor da barra */
    float: left;                   /* ficar horizontal */
    width: 120px;                  /* tamanho da barra */
    height: 50px;                  /* altura da barra */
    display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;             /* ficar a esqueda*/
    line-height: 22px;             /* mover o submenu*/
    font-size: 24px;               /* tamanho da letra*/
    position: relative;
}

.menu ul li:hover{
    background-color:#33adff;       /* muda a cor do submenu quando  metes la o rato */
}

.menu ul{
    padding: 0px;                   /* move a barra para a direita */
}

.menu ul ul{
    display: none;                  /* para  o sub sub menu ficar invisivel*/
}

.menu ul li:hover > ul{             /* para quando por o rato no menu ementa, aparecer o sub menu*/
    display:block;
}

.menu ul ul ul{                     /* SOBRE AS CARNES E PEIXES*/
    margin-left:120px;              /* mover para a direita*/
    top: 0px;                       /* ir para baixo*/
    position: absolute;
}

.menu ul ul li:hover{               /* SUBMENU DA EMENTA*/
    background-color:#80bfff;       /* cor do  submenu*/
}

.menu ul ul ul li:hover{            /* SUBSUBMENU DA EMENTA*/
    background-color:#80bfff;       /* cor*/
}

/* Css Blur do Thomas*/
.menu a{                            /* OS MENUS*/
    color:black;                    /* cor do texto*/
    text-decoration: none;          /* sem decoração*/
}
.menu li {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.menu:hover li {
    -webkit-filter: blur(1.5px);
}
.menu:hover li:hover, .menu:hover li:hover ul li{
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
}
/* Alinhamento horizontal do Menu no Centro da Página*/
nav {
    width: 480px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
/* Alinhamento horizontal da Imagem no Centro da Página*/
.hero {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero">
    <img src="33.png" href="quinta.html" width="150" height="150">
</div>
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <div>
        <li><a href="Restaurante.html">Restaurante</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ementa</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Entrada.html">Entrada</a></li>
                <li><a href="Prato Principal.html">Prato Principal</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="Carnes.html">Carnes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Peixes.html">Peixes</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Vegetariano.html">Vegetariano</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="Sobremesas.html">Sobremesas</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="Reserva.html">Reserva</a></li>
        <li><a href="Contacto.html">Contacto</a></li>
    </div>
    </ul>
    <br><br><br><br>
</nav>
```

Tinha um Erro no seu HTML a Imagem Estava por fora do `<body>`, também corrigi isso no HTML acima

```
<!-- Não se deve colocar a imagem fora Body -->
<img src="33.png" href="quinta.html" width="150" height="150">
<body>
```

Comment: sim, funciona muito  obrigado

Comment: @LucasSintra que bom que deu certo! Se a minha resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marcar a Resposta com "Aceita" ✔

Answer (score 0):

Lucas, para você ter esse resultado, você precisa trabalhar com o `filter` e adicionar o `blur`, que da o efeito de borrão.

Adicione essa linha no seu css.

```
.menu li {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.menu:hover li {
    -webkit-filter: blur(1.5px);
}
.menu:hover li:hover, .menu:hover li:hover ul li{
    -webkit-filter: blur(0);
}
```

Comment: eu  acabei  de adicionar isso  no  meu  codigo  e so piorou. a imagem de funndo  desapareceu a submenu aumenteu  de tamanho  entre outra coisa.

Comment: @LucasSintra, eu não sei como está o seu código, mas o que você forneceu está funcionando tranquilamente, sem dar conflito. http://sites.fullprog.com/testes/blur/

Comment: sim, o meu código  está bom  mas eu  queria fazer uma barra com os submenus no meio da barra. mas não  estou  a conseguir fazer a barra.

Comment: Tem algum layout pra ajudar a saber como é essa barra, da onde ela vem, como ela fica? Sem saber disso fica difícil te ajudar.

Comment: posso  mandar o link  de um restaurante que tem  o que eu quero  fazer?

Comment: @LucasSintra, pode.

Comment: Está aqui. https://www.restaurantlarive.nl/nl/

Comment: Esse é o mesmo que você mencionou antes, e não tem essa barra que você está tentando colocar, apenas o `filter blur`. O que tem a mais ali é um `background` e um `border` onde está dando o `hover`

Comment: mas se eu  por o seu  código no meu  código não funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia!

Coloca a sua tag img pra dentro da tag body, não sei se está gerando algum dos seus problemas, mas pode gerar problemas mais pra frente.
Quanto ao blur, não achei ele provavelmente seja feito com um script, pois não há classe active nos links também. Fiz assim no código que mandou e funcionou aqui:

```
$('.menu li').hover(function(){
  $('.menu li').css('filter', 'blur(3px)');
  $(this).css('filter', 'none');
})
```

Espero ter ajudado, abraços!